# Pytorch lightning progress bar not working in AWS Sagemaker Jupyter Lab

Tags: progress-bar, jupyter-lab, amazon-sagemaker, pytorch-lightning

We started using Sagemaker Jupyter Lab to run a few Depp Learning experiments we previously ran on GoogleColabPro+. The training starts fine and everything seems to work, however, the progress bar appears as follows:

**Validation sanity check: 0it [00:00, ?it/s]
Training: 0it [00:00, ?it/s]**

The progress bar was working fine on GoogleColab. I tried uninstalling ipywidgets as [suggested here](https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/issues/11208), but still no luck. Anyone has an idea of how to fix the problem?

Below you will find a copy of the TrainerFunction I am using.

```
class T5FineTuner(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, hparams):
        super(T5FineTuner, self).__init__()
        self.hparams = hparams

        self.model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(hparams['model_name_or_path'])
        self.tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained(hparams['tokenizer_name_or_path'])

    def hparams(self):
        return self.hparams

    def is_logger(self):
        return True #self.trainer.proc_rank <= 0

    def forward(
            self, input_ids, attention_mask=None, decoder_input_ids=None, decoder_attention_mask=None, labels=None
    ):
        return self.model(
            input_ids,
            attention_mask=attention_mask,
            decoder_input_ids=decoder_input_ids,
            decoder_attention_mask=decoder_attention_mask,
            labels=labels,
        )

    def _step(self, batch):
        labels = batch["target_ids"]
        labels[labels[:, :] == self.tokenizer.pad_token_id] = -100

        outputs = self(
            input_ids=batch["source_ids"],
            attention_mask=batch["source_mask"],
            labels=labels,
            decoder_attention_mask=batch['target_mask']
        )

        loss = outputs[0]

        return loss

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        loss = self._step(batch)

        tensorboard_logs = {"train_loss": loss}
        return {"loss": loss, "log": tensorboard_logs}

    def training_epoch_end(self, outputs):
        avg_train_loss = torch.stack([x["loss"] for x in outputs]).mean()
        tensorboard_logs = {"avg_train_loss": avg_train_loss}
        # return {"avg_train_loss": avg_train_loss, "log": tensorboard_logs, 'progress_bar': tensorboard_logs}

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        loss = self._step(batch)
        return {"val_loss": loss}

    def validation_epoch_end(self, outputs):
        avg_loss = torch.stack([x["val_loss"] for x in outputs]).mean()
        tensorboard_logs = {"val_loss": avg_loss}
        return {"avg_val_loss": avg_loss, "log": tensorboard_logs, 'progress_bar': tensorboard_logs}

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        "Prepare optimizer and schedule (linear warmup and decay)"

        model = self.model
        no_decay = ["bias", "LayerNorm.weight"]
        optimizer_grouped_parameters = [
            {
                "params": [p for n, p in model.named_parameters() if not any(nd in n for nd in no_decay)],
                "weight_decay": self.hparams['weight_decay'],
            },
            {
                "params": [p for n, p in model.named_parameters() if any(nd in n for nd in no_decay)],
                "weight_decay": 0.0,
            },
        ]
        optimizer = AdamW(optimizer_grouped_parameters, lr=self.hparams['learning_rate'], eps=self.hparams['adam_epsilon'])
        self.opt = optimizer
        return [optimizer]

    def optimizer_step(self, epoch=None, batch_idx=None, optimizer=None, optimizer_idx=None, optimizer_closure=None,  second_order_closure=None, on_tpu=False, using_native_amp=False, using_lbfgs=False):
        # if self.trainer.use_tpu:
        #     xm.optimizer_step(optimizer)
        # else:
        optimizer.step(closure=optimizer_closure)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        self.lr_scheduler.step()

    def get_tqdm_dict(self):
        tqdm_dict = {"loss": "{:.3f}".format(self.trainer.avg_loss), "lr": self.lr_scheduler.get_last_lr()[-1]}

        return tqdm_dict

    def train_dataloader(self):
        train_dataset = get_dataset(tokenizer=self.tokenizer, type_path="translated_train", args=self.hparams)
        dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=self.hparams['train_batch_size'], drop_last=True, shuffle=True,
                                num_workers=4)
        t_total = (
                (len(dataloader.dataset) // (self.hparams['train_batch_size'] * max(1, self.hparams['n_gpu'])))
                // self.hparams['gradient_accumulation_steps']
                * float(self.hparams['num_train_epochs'])
        )
        scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(
            self.opt, num_warmup_steps=self.hparams['warmup_steps'], num_training_steps=t_total
        )
        self.lr_scheduler = scheduler
        return dataloader

    def val_dataloader(self):
        val_dataset = get_dataset(tokenizer=self.tokenizer, type_path="test_2k", args=self.hparams)
        return DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=self.hparams['eval_batch_size'], num_workers=4)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class LoggingCallback(pl.Callback):
    def on_validation_end(self, trainer, pl_module):
        logger.info("***** Validation results *****")
        if pl_module.is_logger():
            metrics = trainer.callback_metrics
            # Log results
            for key in sorted(metrics):
                if key not in ["log", "progress_bar"]:
                    logger.info("{} = {}\n".format(key, str(metrics[key])))

    def on_test_end(self, trainer, pl_module):
        logger.info("***** Test results *****")

        if pl_module.is_logger():
            metrics = trainer.callback_metrics

            # Log and save results to file
            output_test_results_file = os.path.join(pl_module.hparams["output_dir"], "test_results.txt")
            with open(output_test_results_file, "w") as writer:
                for key in sorted(metrics):
                    if key not in ["log", "progress_bar"]:
                        logger.info("{} = {}\n".format(key, str(metrics[key])))
                        writer.write("{} = {}\n".format(key, str(metrics[key])))
```